# VPN Connection using VB in Visual Studion 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, vpn

Using Visual Studio 2013 and coding with VB, not C#, I need to be able to create a VPN connection. I have been looking for several days and tried several things but nothing works. I will also need it to disconnect. I have done this in a batch file using the following.

rasdial  "VPN Connection"  user  password

rasdial  "China VPN Connection"  /disconnect

obviously that does not work in VB.NET.

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

```
rasdial  "VPN Connection"  user  password
```

End Sub

Comment: why not run the batch file from vb?

Comment: Because I need the password to be Encrypted and to have it all oin one file instead of two.

Comment: Process.Start("rasdial.exe", """VPN Connection"" User Password").  My issue was trying to use variables instead of having the values hard coded. Does anyone know how I would properly insert my variables so that the values do not need to be hard coded?

Comment: Isn't that the same question as 'how do I store values'?

Comment: @Rob; I did not ask "How do I store values". I have solved my issues.